# How to register a custom ILogger so that all Unhandled Exceptions get logged

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, blazor-client-side

**Please see [Log unhandled exceptions to custom logger](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/pull/19606) on github. Apparently Up to Preview 2 Blazor logs unhandled Exceptions via Console.WriteLine. This will be changed in Preview 3 to use ILogger.**

As described [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/pull/19606) Blazor uses configured ILogger instances to log **all unhandled** Exceptions. However I can not get it to work. Searching the web I found sites using an ILoggerProvider or an ILoggerFactory which adds to my confusion.

Which services do I have to configure how to log unhandled Exceptions?

**Update**:
I want to add a second non-console logger and I cannot get that second one to work. The built in console logger from Blazor works fine

**Update 2**:

Here is a list of everything I tried so far. **None** of the following worked and sent Unhandled exceptions to MyLogger (In some cases I got all *other* Messages forwarded to MyLogger)

I tried to register the Logger:

```
public static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)  {
    services.AddSingleton<ILogger, MyLogger>();
    services.AddSingleton(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(MyLogger<>)));
```

I tried to register the Provider:

```
services.AddSingleton(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<ILoggerProvider, MyLoggerProvider>());
services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<ILoggerProvider, MyLoggerProvider>());
services.AddSingleton<ILoggerProvider, MyLoggerProvider>();
```

I tried to register the Provider with the existing ILoggerFactory:

```
host.Services.GetService<ILoggerFactory>().AddProvider(new MyLoggerProvider());
```

I tried to register my MyLoggerFactory:

```
services.AddSingleton<ILoggerFactory, MyLoggerFactory>();
```

My implementation of ILogger:

```
public class MyLogger : ILogger
{
    public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"MyLogger.exception='{exception}'");
    }

    public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state)
    {
        return new EmptyDisposable();
    }

    internal class EmptyDisposable : IDisposable 
    {
        public void Dispose()
        {
        }
    }
}

public class MyLogger<T> : ILogger<T>
{
    public void Log<TState>(
        LogLevel logLevel,
        EventId eventId,
        TState state,
        Exception exception,
        Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"MyLogger<generic>.exception='{exception}'");
    }

    public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state)
    {
        return new MyLogger.EmptyDisposable();
    }
}
```

My Implementation of ILoggerProvider

```
public class MyLoggerProvider: ILoggerProvider
{
    public void Dispose()
    {

    }

    public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"MyLoggerProvider.categoryName='{categoryName}'");
        return new MyLogger();
    }
}
```

My Implementation of ILoggerFactory

```
public class MyLoggerFactory : ILoggerFactory
{
    public MyLoggerFactory()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"MyLoggerFactory.ctor");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"MyLoggerFactory.categoryName='{categoryName}'");
        return new MyLogger();
    }

    public void AddProvider(ILoggerProvider provider)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"MyLoggerFactory.AddProvider");
    }
}
```

Comment: So I've never used Blazer, but I took a quick look at the docs.  I guess I am a little uncertain about what you are asking.  Are you saying Blazer doesn't catch your unhandled exceptions?  Or are you saying Blazer doesn't catch its own unhandled exceptions?  Or are you saying you want to add a second non-Console logger and you cannot get that second logger to work?  (If that is the question, is the Blazer configured Console Logger working?)

Comment: @FrankMerrow I want to add a second non-console logger and I cannot get that second one to work. The built in console logger from Blazor works fine.

Comment: Can you please show us what you have tried so far?  Please, add it to the question above.

Comment: @FrankMerrow I updateded the question with everything I tried so far

Comment: Instead of
Instead of "host.Services.GetService<ILoggerFactory>().AddProvider(new MyLoggerProvider());"
I think you will want either / or so either a) "host.Services.AddProvider(new MyLoggerProvider());" to register the factory or b) "host.Services.GetService<ILoggerFactory>();" to get a logger factory instance.

Answer (score 1):

The test code can give you an idea of how to register your logger.
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/pull/19606/files#diff-106bbead18cff2ed036495cc7c9dbdd1

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILoggerFactory>(services =>
{
    var originalLogger = (ILoggerFactory)Activator.CreateInstance(
         originalLoggerDescriptor.ImplementationType,
         new object[] { services });
    return new PrependMessageLoggerFactory("Custom logger", originalLogger);
});
```

In short:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILoggerFactory>(services => new MyLoggerFactory());
```